# Word for an activity that one does not care for?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, idiom-requests

I'm looking for a word or phrase to describe an activity which is not liked by everybody. You either like it or you don't. This word or phrase shouldn't be critical. I don't mean to say that somebody's interests don't make any sense. What I do mean is that I'm not someone who might be interested in this kind of activity, I'm not the right person to take it up.

For example:

> Would you like to try canoeing? - Not really. It's ... (only for those who really like this kind of activity but I'm not one of them).

Comment: There are two ways this question can go - are you looking for a word that describes something *you*, aka an individual, doesn't like? Or are you looking for a word for something people generally do not like?

Comment: @BruceWayne Given the example (in particular the **"but I'm not one of them"** part), I'd say it's an individual's lack of interest in the activity.

Comment: @BruceWayne A word or phrase which describes my lack of interest but doesn't sound rude to others because I don't mean to say that someone's interests are strange or something.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Would you like to try canoeing? - Not really. It's ***not to my taste/liking***.
>   Would you like to try canoeing? - Not really. It's ***not right/just up/down my alley/street***.

MW:

> **[to someone's taste](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/to%20someone's%20taste)**
>   *idiom*
>   : liked by someone
>   The movie was not to their taste.
>
> **[to someone's liking](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/to%20someone's%20liking)**
>   *idiom*
>   : appealing or enjoyable to someone
>   She reads poetry, but fiction is
>   much more to her liking.

TFD(idioms):

> **[right up your alley](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Right+Up+My+Alley)** [mainly AMERICAN] If something is right up your alley, it is the kind of thing you like or know about.
>   This
>   should be right up my alley but, despite the film's special effects, I
>   found it rather boring.
>   **Note**: You can also say that something is right down your alley.
>   I'll need whatever information you can turn up within the week. This
>   case seems right down your alley.
>   **Note**: The usual British expression is ***right up your street***.
>
> Collins COBUILD Idioms Dictionary, 3rd ed. © HarperCollins Publishers 2012

Comment: I've never seen "right up my alley" used in the negative like that.

Comment: Yeah up your alley is generally positive...

Answer (score 27):

**It's not everybody's/my/... cup of tea.**

> *not (one's) cup of tea:*
>
> Not something one prefers, desires, enjoys, or cares about.
>
> *Thank you for the invitation, but long-distance cycling just isn't really my cup of tea.*
>
> *When I found out that reading wasn't his cup of tea, I knew that there wasn't much of a relationship in store between us.*

[Farlex Dictionary of Idioms. © 2015 Farlex, Inc, all rights reserved.](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/not+cup+of+tea)

.........

*not one's cup of tea*

> Fig. not one's choice or preference. (Used to describe an activity you
>   do not enjoy. Can sound somewhat affected.)
>
> *You three visit the museum without me. Looking at fussy old paintings is not my cup of tea.*
>
> *Going to church, Mary said, was not her cup of tea.*

[McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs. © 2002 by The McGraw-Hill Companies, Inc.](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/not+cup+of+tea)

The more general statement *not everybody's cup of tea* is also idiomatic; it appears as a title in [this article in the Economist](https://www.economist.com/node/18483277) (on voting reform in the UK). As one might expect, there is more of a 'British English' flavour. But as [this thread](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/279086/is-the-expression-ones-cup-of-tea-used-in-american-english) shows, it is not uncommon in the United States.

Answer (score 12):

You could simply say [**not my kind of thing**](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/somebody-s-kind-of-person-thing-place-etc):

> **somebody’s kind of person/thing/place etc**
>
> the type of person, thing, place etc that someone usually likes

Your example:

> — Would you like to try canoeing?
> — Not really. It's **not my kind of thing**.

---

Another good and very common expression would be [**not one's bag**](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/is+not+my+bag):

> To not be something one prefers, desires, enjoys, or cares about.

Example:

> Thank you for the invitation, but long-distance cycling just **isn't really my bag**.

Comment: Also often simplified to "it's not my thing."

Answer (score 8):

You could say **[it / canoeing] is not for me**, according to [Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/something-is-not-for-somebody):

> **something is not for somebody**: used to say that something is not the kind of thing that someone likes or will enjoy

In your example:

> Would you like to try canoeing? - Not really. It's **not for me**.

Or alternatively:

> Would you like to try canoeing? - No, canoeing is **not really for me**.

Attribution: "Something Is Not for Somebody." Something Is Not for Somebody | Meaning of Something Is Not for Somebody in Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English | LDOCE. Accessed April 09, 2018. https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/something-is-not-for-somebody.

Answer (score 5):

#### For canoeing specifically:

> Q) Would you like to try canoeing?
>
> A) No thanks, canoeing **doesn't [float my boat](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/floats+my+boat)**

Answer (score 2):

Do you remember your first taste of black coffee? I remember asking as a child why adults liked it so much if it tasted so bad. I was told it was **an acquired taste**, which may be what you're looking for.

Another phrase that might fit is **you either love it or you hate it**.

Answer (score 2):

> 1. I'm not **[into](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/into)** canoeing. (informal)
> 2. Sorry, canoeing's **[not for me](http://www.nme.com/news/film/danny-boyle-on-directing-next-bond-film-it-s-not-f-868320)** (neutral)
> 3. Can't say I'm **[a fan of](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/fan)** ____. (informal)
> 4. I'm not **[wild about](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/wild)** ___. (informal)
> 5. I'm not [terribly] **[keen on](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/keen)** ___ (formal)

UPDATE

> 6. Canoeing is **[out of my comfort zone](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/comfort-zone)**
> 7. It's **out(side) of [my wheelhouse](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/wheelhouse)**
> 8. I'm **out of my [element](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/element)**

The OP's sample sentence would need to be tweaked a little

> Would you like to try canoeing? - No, **I'm out of my element** where canoeing is concerned.

[Users are free to add any other expressions or idioms that come to mind.]

Answer (score 1):

A related concept is "acquired taste", which technically refers to something which hardly anybody likes the first time they try it, but that *some* grow to quite like. Strong cheeses, for example, or peaty whisky. But I do also hear it used, as a bit of a euphemism, for things which hardly anybody likes at all.

In arts and culture, "cult favourite" fits the definition.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is exactly what you seek, but **Floccinaucinihilipilification** is sure to bring colour to your vocabulary ! :-)
(—flocksi-nausi-nihili-pili-fication-)

The act of finding something unimportant or plain bs. — ((what can I say except you’re welcome.)) ;P

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).